# Chaining Queueable Apex with Callouts Run Into Loop

Tags: apex, trigger, rest-api, asynchronous, queueable-apex

I have a queueable class that is triggered from a trigger that makes a callout. I wanted to use Queueable for scenarios where I need to insert 3-5k of records and eventually make 3-5k callouts. But the queueable goes into a loop even when I insert only 5 records and  it takes so long to abort the job once it's started. any help is appreciated

```apex
trigger LeadTrigger on Lead (before insert, before update) {
    List<Id> userIds =  new List<Id>();
    for (Lead objLead : Trigger.new) {
        if(!System.isFuture() || !System.isQueueable()){
            userIds.add(objLead.Id);
            }
        }
        if (userIds != null && (!System.isFuture() || !System.isQueueable())) {
            System.enqueueJob(new KeyApiQueueable (userIds));
        } 
    }
```

Queueable

```apex
public with sharing class KeyApiQueueable implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {
    public List<Id> recordIds;

    public KeyApiQueueable (list<id> ids){
        this.recordIds = ids;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
        Lead[] leadsToUpdate = new lead[0];
        while(recordIds.size() > 0 && leadsToUpdate.size() < 100) { // Max 100 callouts allowed here
            Id nextId = recordIds.remove(0);
            leadsToUpdate.add(processPayload(nextId));
        }
        update leadsToUpdate;

        if(recordIds.size() > 0) {
            System.enqueueJob(this);
        }
    }

    public static Lead processPayload(Id recordId){
        List<Lead> leadAccount = [SELECT Id, deger1__c, deger2__c FROM Lead WHERE Id =: recordId];
        Lead leadAccounts = leadAccount[0];
        Integer Value2;
        Integer Value3;

        HttpRequest request= new HttpRequest();
        request.setMethod('GET');
        request.setEndPoint('https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/69095/tasteWidget.json?apiKey=b454430f54a14e');

        try{
            Http http=new Http();
            HttpResponse response=http.send(request);

            if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                Map<String,Object> results = (Map<String,Object>)Json.deserializeUntyped(response.getBody());
                Value2= Integer.valueof(results.get('sweetness'));
                Value3 = Integer.valueof(results.get('saltiness'));
            }   
            leadAccounts.deger1__c = Value3;
            leadAccounts.deger2__c = Value2;  
        }
        catch(System.CalloutException e){
            system.debug('Error-' + e.getMessage());  
        }
        return leadAccounts;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (userIds != null && (!System.isFuture() || !System.isQueueable())) {
```

Is incorrect. If you're in a future call, you won't be in a queueable call, and if you're in a queueable call, you won't be in a future call. Both TRUE || FALSE and FALSE || TRUE will result in a TRUE result every time. You meant to use &&, instead:

```
if (userIds.size() > 0 && !System.isFuture() && !System.isQueueable()) {
```

I know this tends to confuse newer programmers, since in normal English, we often say "or" instead of "and" in some places. You may want to refresh your memory on how && and || work with some truth tables. Once you get used to it, you'll hardly ever make that mistake.

Also, note that `userIds` can't be null, no need to check for that here, but you probably want to check if the list is *empty* first.

Comment: I will go over the logical operators once again, Thank you @sfdcfox that fixed the issue.